# MVC5 Controller no action found using Route Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following MVC Controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/SystemCheck")]
public class SystemCheckController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    [Route("EnvironmentValidate")]
    [RequiresPrivilegeMVC((int)PrivilegeType.SystemCheck)]
    public IEnumerable<EnvironmentValidation> Get()
    {
        return FilteredEnvironmentValidate();
    }
```

I want to be able to access it these two ways:

1. http://localhost/Perform/API/SystemCheck/EnvironmentValidate
2. http://localhost/Perform/API/SystemCheck/

When I try option 2 I get a valid response. However, when I try option 1 I get:

*{
  "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/Perform/API/SystemCheck/EnvironmentValidate'.",
  "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'SystemCheck' that matches the name 'EnvironmentValidate'."
}*

Is it not finding my controller action because the method name is called `Get` but the route is specifying it as "EnvironmentValidate"?

Here is how I have configured my RouteConfig.cs:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiGet",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { action = "Get" },
            constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") }
        );
```

Any ideas of what I'm missing?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not super knowledge in routes for MVC. However if I had to take a guess, I'd say your first option is working not because you set the Route attribute on it with "", but because "Get" is set as the default in you RouteConfig. Also, if you want to use the MVC Controllers as an API, it is suggested to use WebAPI instead (you might have a good reason not to, just noting in case you didn't know about it)

Comment: I'm pretty sure when mapping routes in MVC, it takes the first match, which in this case should be his attribute based routing.

Comment: You might be mixing MVC and WebApi components. ApiController is a WebApi construct and you need to to use the WebApi attribute routing.  Each namespace has exactly the same class defined but they don't work across each other.  https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to use MVC attribute routing with a WebApi controller.

The `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()` is ignoring the attributes (since there is a mismatch between the namespace it is expecting), so only the `DefaultApiGet` route is getting mapped.

You can switch `ApiController` to `Controller`, so that you use the MVC controller, which matches the current attribute routing you are using (assuming that the `Route` attribute you are using is in the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace).

Or you can update the namespace to `System.Web.Http` which is the WebApi namespace, and call `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()` instead.

More instructions here https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2 for setting up WebApi attribute routing.